# AttributeError: module 'apache_beam' has no attribute 'options'

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow, google-dataflow

I am getting the following error when running an Apache Beam pipeline. The full error code is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-870f9c2f41e5> in <module>
     39                  file_path_prefix=os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'ptp-dataset.csv'))))
     40 
---> 41 preprocess()

<ipython-input-12-870f9c2f41e5> in preprocess()
     22       'requirements_file': 'requirements.txt'
     23     }
---> 24     opts = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
     25     RUNNER = 'DataflowRunner' # 'DirectRunner'
     26 

AttributeError: module 'apache_beam' has no attribute 'options'
```

The code generating the error is when I try to call the `PipelineOptions` class.

```
 opts = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
 RUNNER = 'DataflowRunner' # 'DirectRunner'
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, `pip install` the latest version of apache-beam by running:

```
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
```

Restart your kernel and then import the class using `options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions`. In this example, change it to:

```
opts = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
RUNNER = 'DataflowRunner'
```